# How can I restrict external logs from being written to system log files like /var/log/secure?

Tags: linux, logging, redhat, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslog on redhat to capture syslog events over udp and tcp and write them out to files.

I want to keep sending local authentications and other OS level events to their standard location, such has /var/log/secure, while routing the events coming in over the network to their respective files.

An example of a rule for external logs might be:

```
$template LOGSOURCE1,"/var/log/external/LOGSOURCE1/%HOSTNAME%.log"
:fromhost-ip, contains, "10.1.2.3" -?LOGSOURCE1
& stop
```

I have no control over how these external syslog messages are formatted / classified.
Some events get routed to the secure and boot logs because of the following standard configurations:

```
1. local7.\*            /var/log/boot.log
2. authpriv.\*;auth.\*  /var/log/secure
```

How can I keep logging normal OS events to these standard OS files, ensuring external events only go to their appropriate output files?

I've tried changing the order of rsyslog.conf, putting my includes before or after these standard local7 and auth rules.  That didn't change anything.
I can stop the problematic events from being logged to /var/log/secure and /var/log/boot by commenting the local7 and auth rules in rsyslog.conf, but then I don't get the local OS entries I'm after.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: I think you can just process the external logs first and use `& ~` (traditional syslog syntax) instead of `& stop`. I'm not 100% sure, but i think `& stop` doesn't work because it is RainerScript syntax - written inside a traditional syslog syntax block. Otherwise you might want to filter by "127.0.0.1" which for sure isn't the most optimal solution.